# What do I need to do to convert the views in my Rails app from HAML to ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I have a Rails app that I'm customizing. The more I work on it, the more I both love and hate HAML. I love that HAML's so clean to look at it, I hate that I can't intuitively trouble shoot with Chrome Inspector or Safari Developer Tools. So, I have gathered that conversion to ERB is the best thing for others in my shoes (designers or other mere mortals with basic knowledge of HTML and CSS, wanting to customize the content in this [open source Rails app](https://github.com/96ready/ready96)).

**What are the steps involved in converting the views from HAML to ERB**
and **what else will I need to change?** ...routes? controllers? anything?

There are a lot of the down-in-the-weeds questions about this, but I'm looking for an overview so I can wrap my head around what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just converting HAML->HTML/ERB You shouldn't have any need to be changing any controllers, routes or models at all. But I wouldn't necessarily recommend taking that route. HAML is great because it stops people being syntactically incorrect in their HTML. It essentially forces you to not make mistakes.

I don't really understand the issue with troubleshooting through chrome/firefox as all it's outputting is HTML at the end of the day.

Comment: The main issue with troubleshooting through chrome/firefox is that what you see there is not a direct match to what you need to find and edit in the source file. This is not a project for dedicated developers, it is for people that are dabbling in development to achieve something relevant to their work in emergency management (e.g. firefighters that are doing some coding).